# Stop draining shard in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

```
--- Sharding Status --- 
  sharding version: { "_id" : 1, "version" : 3 }
  shards:
    {  "_id" : "set1",  "host" : "set1/m1.example.com:27018,mr1.example.com:27018,mrb1.example.com:27018" }
    {  "_id" : "set2",  "draining" : true,  "host" : "set2/m2.example.com:27018,mr2.example.com:27018,mrb2.example.com:27018" }
    {  "_id" : "set3",  "host" : "set3/m3.example.com:27018,mr3.example.com:27018,mrb3.example.com:27018" }
```

by mistake I remove set2 from the shard cluster, and it starts draining, how do i stop the draining ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

RemoveShard will start the draining process but there is no StopRemoveShard command. It is alright there isn't a command yet since it is easy to stop the process manually.

Draining is just a state where the balancer starts to move chunks off the marked shard (which is draining). You can stop draining by removing the special "draining" field on the shard metadata configuration.

```
//connect to a mongos server with the mongo javascript shell
use config
//unset draining from all shards
db.shards.update({},{$unset:{draining:true}}, false, true)
```

After this is done the balancer will go back to normal balancing, and no longer drain the shard.

Comment: Is it advisable to this since mongodb documentation specifically advises against modifying contents of `config` database manually? - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/config-database/#config.shards