# MongoDb stop draining side effects

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

We decreased the number of shards in our atlas cluster on atlas' cluster settings UI. A secondary shard was removed and, as expected, the draining has started. The problem is, that our application has become slow. I saw that [the draining can be stopped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11813664/stop-draining-shard-in-mongodb), we would like to do that and later, after our business hours restart/resume it.

Will stopping the draining have any side effect? After we stopped the draining the remaining chunks will be still available for the application? Will it be enough to just set the flag and the draining will be continued? What could go wrong if I unset the flag and set it later?

We are using MongoDB v4.2.

Comment: You would probably have better luck asking MongoDB support if you are a paying customer.

Comment: Can you even unset/set that flag in an Atlas cluster?  Since Atlas is a managed service, I would be surprised if you can.